# Criar moldura para lista de item

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

Preciso criar uma moldura para um item de uma listView porém não tenho ideia de como fazer isso [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode utilizar [CardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview.html) para obter este tipo de efeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje é recomendado o uso do *RecyclerView* ou *CardView* no lugar do *ListView*, mas, se ainda assim, se você precisa fazer uso do *ListView* que no caso terá layout customizado, veja a documentação do Android sobre Adapter para *ListView*. Uma possibilidade seria estender de [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

Basicamente, você usaria na *View* onde ficará sua lista um *ListView* convencional e criaria um adaptador no Java com as especificidades do seu *ListView*, incluindo o layout e métodos do que deve ocorrer ao pressionar um item da lista ou pressionar durante um tempo maior.

Já na atividade relacionada ao *ListView*, crie um objeto do adapter e faça uso do método *setAdapter(ListAdapter l)* para vincular seu adaptador personalizado ao *ListView*.

Você pode conferir [aqui](http://blog.alura.com.br/personalizando-uma-listview-no-android/) um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser customizar a ListView, eu recomendo esse tutorial aí:

https://androiddevbr.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/tudo-sobre-listview/

Explicam tudo direitinho!
Espero ter ajudado!